# Format a PivotChart data label based on the x axis

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am trying to find a way (if possible) to change the text color of a data label to red, if the X axis happens to be a certain label.

The issue I am having is that my charts are dynamic (are refreshed daily via PowerPivot and have date and other slicers that change what data is displayed in the charts), so even if I color the data label red, when the charts are refreshed, it reverts back to the original black font.

For example, in the image below, I have a chart that is tracking tickets by the amount of days that they have been open; the goal is to have all tickets resolved within 45 days; so, when the charts shows any data in the "45+" section, I would like the font of that data label to be red.

Sample of my chart:

[image: Sample of my chart:]

In my research I was able to find and modify some code that make all the data labels red, but I am very new to using VBA to manipulate charts and would appreciate some help. The code I have so far:

```
Sub ChrtTest()
Dim i As Long

Sheets("Dashboard").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("DB_Chrt_1").Activate
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select

With ActiveChart
    For i = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
        With .SeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill
            Select Case .Parent.Parent.Name
                Case "45+"
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    With .Parent.Parent
                        .ApplyDataLabels
                        With .DataLabels
                            .Position = xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd
                            .Font.Color = vbYellow
                        End With
                    End With
                Case Else
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    With .Parent.Parent
                        .ApplyDataLabels
                        With .DataLabels
                            .Position = xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd
                            .Font.Color = vbRed
                        End With
                    End With
             End Select
        End With
        Next i
      End With

End Sub
```

Comment: for starters I would change `vbYellow` to `vbRed` and `vbRed` to `vbBlack`. Otherwise, what does the code *not* do for you that you expect it to do?

Comment: I would advise in learning VBA to grab hold of object types and references rather than all that `.select` and `parent.parent` coding. You can use dots and go through, but if you need to manipulate certain objects often, then getting it referenced well can i)ease your debugging, ii) simplify your codewriting, iii) improve your knowledge of the Object Model, and iv) get intellisense to provide you with the available methods and properties of the object...

Comment: @MacroMarc Thank you for the advice, do you know of any specific material I could use to learn more about objects in VBA?

Comment: MSDN doesnt have good explanations sometimes, and the examples are weird, but it's the most complete reference(being that VBA is a MS language). Intellisense can be very helpful once you get the general swing of things in Excel objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some code to get you started:

```
Sub template()

    Dim pc As Chart
    Set pc = Sheets("Dashboard").ChartObjects("DB_Chrt_1").Chart

    Dim ax As Axis
    Set ax = pc.Axes(xlCategory)

    Dim dSet As Series
    Set dSet = pc.SeriesCollection(1)

    Dim dPoints As Points
    Set dPoints = dSet.Points

    pc.ApplyDataLabels

    For i = 1 To dPoints.Count
        If ax.CategoryNames(i) = "45+" Then
            With dPoints(i).DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters
               .Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            End With
        End If
   Next i

End Sub
```

This should set the dataLabel text to red. You can fool around with other properties as well

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful; I will definitely be learning more on how to grab and manipulate objects in VBA.